# Column values which depends on another column with conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have an example data as:

```
datetime             temperature   season
2021-04-10 01:00:00.    10.        Heating season
2021-04-10 01:00:00.    26.        Heating season
2021-07-10 01:00:00.    16.        Cooling season
2021-07-10 01:00:00.    30.        Cooling season
```

I would like to create a new column called new_temperature: a) if temperature column is less than 18 and the season is heating season, new_temperature should be 25 otherwise 18 if its cooling season.
b) If temperature column is greater than 25 and the season is cooling season, the new_temperature column should be 18 otherwise 22 if its heating season.

The example output is shown below:

```
datetime             temperature   season.         new_temperature
2021-04-10 01:00:00.    10.        Heating season.    25
2021-04-10 01:00:00.    26.        Heating season.    22
2021-07-10 01:00:00.    16.        Cooling season.    18
2021-07-10 01:00:00.    30.        Cooling season.    18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.select` with 4 conditions:

```py
cond_1 = (df.temperature < 18) & (df.season == "Heating season")
cond_2 = (df.temperature < 18) & (df.season != "Heating season")
cond_3 = (df.temperature > 25) & (df.season == "Cooling season")
cond_4 = (df.temperature > 25) & (df.season != "Cooling season")

conditions = [cond_1, cond_2, cond_3, cond_4]
choices = [25, 18, 18, 22]

df["new_temperature"] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

to get

```
               datetime  temperature          season  new_temperature
0  2021-04-10 01:00:00.         10.0  Heating season               25
1  2021-04-10 01:00:00.         26.0  Heating season               22
2  2021-07-10 01:00:00.         16.0  Cooling season               18
3  2021-07-10 01:00:00.         30.0  Cooling season               18
```

Note: Since your conditions are not mutually exclusive, you might want to provide a `default` value to `np.select` as the last parameter. In case no condition matches, it will be placed into the result.